# Gdscript Bug or strange behaviour

Tags: arrays, gdscript

I've noticed some strange behaviour in gdscript.

when you declare variables

```
var value = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
var values = []
```

and append one to the other

```
values.append(value)
```

and then change something in the array

```
value[1] = 1
```

If you would then print the results [print(value, values)]

You get

```
prints: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0][[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

expected behaviour

```
prints: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0][[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that, in GDScript, when you append the array `value` to `values`, you're actually appending it's reference to the array. So you end up with an array `values` which has as it's first entry a reference to the array `value`. So when you change the value of the reference in `values`, you're also changing it for your original variable.

for further reading, check out this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science))

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in gdscript are passed by the reference, so when you append an array to other array, it only stores the pointer to the first array, so every change made in first array will be visible in the second array. What you want to do is to copy the first array and append that copy to the second array.

In gdscript currently there is no direct method to copy an array. Maybe this will change with godot 4.0. Now you can use:

```
values.append([] + value)
```